# RollBack() JPA + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, transações

Estou com um problema ao persistir várias informações em uma mesma transação, caso algo de errado uma parte da informação fica gravada no banco e o `rollback()` não é executado.

Segue um exemplo:

```
try 
   {


    em = ConnectionHib.emf.createEntityManager();

    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Recibo recibo = new Recibo();
    Log log = new Log();

    em.createQuery("UPDATE Numeracao s SET s.fcNoRecibo = s.fcNoRecibo+1 WHERE s.emp= :emp ")
    .setParameter("emp", emp.getCodigo())
    .executeUpdate();       

    recibo.setNoRecibo(noRecibo);       
    log.setnorecibo(noRecibo); 

    em.persist(recibo);
    em.persist(log);


    em.getTransaction().commit();

   } 
   catch (Exception e) 
   {

    em.getTransaction().rollback();

    throw e;
   } 
     finally 
   {
    em.close();
   }
```

Se algo de errado no insert de log, os dados de recibo e o comando update na numeração é gravado no banco.

Erro apresentado:

```
jan 16, 2018 11:06:12 AM
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions WARN: SQL
Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000 jan 16, 2018 11:06:12 AM  
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR:
Column ‘COD_OPERACAO’ cannot be null jan 16, 2018 11:06:12 AM  
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release INFO:
HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements jan 
16, 2018 11:06:12 AM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl 
mapManagedFlushFailure ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush 
[org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute 
statement] javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing 
the transaction at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.
convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:75) at  
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.
commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
```

O que pode ser feito para que o rollback() funcione corretamente??

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="ConnectionData" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>          
        </properties>   
        <!-- <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.20:3306/basedados" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties> -->
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Versão do Hibernate é a 5.2.4

Comment: Qual error que é mostrado?

Comment: Ai a exception, eu forco um erro em recibo para testar o rollback, mas mesmo assim os dados são persistidos.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione o seu `persistence.xml` e a versão do Hibernate que você está utilizando.

Comment: Está ai o persistence

Answer (score 0):

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions ERROR: Column ‘COD_OPERACAO’ cannot be null jan 16, 2018 11:06:12 AM
```

Codigo operção não pode ser nulo veja isso e execute novamente!!

```
catch (RuntimeException  e) {
   em.getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e;
}finally{
    em.getTransaction().commit();
   em.close();
 }
```

Comment: Sim eu sei, eu estou forçando esse erro, o problema é o rollback que não é executado.

Comment: troca Exception por  RuntimeException. Acho que vc pode forca o error de outra maneira..

Comment: Troquei mas o resultado ainda é o mesmo.

Comment: catch (PersistenceException e) achoq é mais especifico! ele estar entrando cath ?

Comment: fiz a troca, ele entra no catch sim, ele só não efetiva o rollback na base de dados.

Comment: Em qual objeto ele não efetua o rollbak ? todos ?

Comment: Isso em todos, ele grava o log, grava o update e dispara o erro em recibo, no entendimento da transação era pra desfazer tudo.

Comment: Mova seu  em.getTransaction().commit(); para finnaly.. testa ai..

Comment: Fiz isso mas mesmo assim gravou.

Comment: @BrunoC. talvez você tenha configurado o auto commit para true, confira as suas configurações do hibernate.

Comment: Auto Commit do Hibernate está false.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza na função

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = java.lang.Exception.class, timeout = DEFAUL_TIMEOUT)
    public void suaFuncao () throws Exception{  }
```